# Ping more than 56 bytes on macOS

Tags: macos, ping, terminal.app

I am on macOS and using terminal to ping. How would I be able to ping more than 56 bytes? I tried to search but was not able to find the answer.

Answer (score 19):

`ping -s` *size* *host*

```
ping -s 1472 target.example.com
```

I gave 1472 as an example because with typical header lengths, that creates a single full-size packet without fragmentation.

For more information about the `ping(1)` command's options, view its manual page with the command `man ping` in the terminal.

Comment: Also, look at the [iperf](https://iperf.fr/) tool

Comment: Also, `-D` means don't fragment.